# access attributes from parent inside child class

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

i'm not familiar with oop in python , just started a project when at first i have a class called phone that have as attributes brand,model,price,quantity and we're asked to create another class child called magasin that will inherit its attributes and where i need to create two functions one toaddphone from class parent and second to display the list of phones that's what i have done so far
class parent :

```
from datetime import datetime


class phone1:
    def __init__(self, brand: str, model: datetime, price: float, quantity: int) -> None:
        self._brand = brand
        self._model = model
        self._price = price
        self._quantity = quantity

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self._brand},{self._model},{self._price},{self._quantity}'

    @property
    def brand(self) -> str:
        return self._brand

    @brand.setter
    def brand(self, brand) -> None:
        self._brand = brand

    @property
    def model(self) -> int:
        return self._model

    @model.setter
    def model(self, model) -> None:
        self._model = model

    @property
    def price(self) -> float:
        return self._price

    @price.setter
    def name(self, price) -> None:
        self._price = price

    @property
    def quantity(self) -> int:
        return self._quantity

    @quantity.setter
    def name(self, quantity) -> None:
        self._quantity = quantity


'''if __name__ == '__main__':

    jumia = phone("nokia", datetime.now().year, 1200.344, 1000)
    print(jumia)'''
```

this is class child magasin

```
from datetime import datetime

from phone import phone1


class magasin(phone1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []


def add_phone(self, brand, model, price, quantity):
    phone = phone1(quantity, brand, model, price, self)
    self.members.append(phone)
    return phone


if __name__ == '__main__':

    test = magasin(add_phone("nokia22", datetime.now().year, 1266.344, 190))
print(test)
```

and  i keep getting this error

```
test = magasin(add_phone("nokia22", datetime.now().year, 1266.344, 190))
TypeError: add_phone() missing 1 required positional argument: 'quantity'
```

i was expecting for test to be printed

Comment: `def add_phone` should be indented to be inside the `magasin` class definition, and it looks like you want to construct a `magasin()` instance first, before calling its method `add_phone`.

Comment: i still getting the same error i put def add_phone inside class magasin and changed the test instruction to  test = magasin.add_phone("nokia22", datetime.now().year, 1266.344, 190)

Comment: That isn't what I described. `magasin` is a class, you need to instantiate first before the methods can be used. Try `test = magasin()` and then `test.add_phone(...)`.